# is this asynchronous behaviour?

Tags: dart, stdin

Why does the below program doesn't print the 'wow', is this the asynchronous behaviour of dart? what did I miss in this piece of code?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:pedantic/pedantic.dart';

bool _asking = false;
String name = '';
Future main() async {
 askUserName();
}

Future askUserName() async {
  _asking = true;
  //feedInfoToTheUser({'info': 'enter a name'});
  //print('enter the name');
 Future.doWhile(() {
    if (name.isNotEmpty) {
      _asking = false;
      print('thank you');
      exit(0);
    }
    return _asking;
  });
  print('wow');
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you want you program to do. You current code does not make much sense since `name` are never updated by any of the code. Also, `Future.doWhile` does not run the code in some other thread. Also, since the method you have given as argument to doWhile is synchronous it will just run immediately forever: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/doWhile.html

Comment: Also, please write an example which actually can be executed. You current code does not declare the `name` and `_asking` variables so it cannot compile.

Comment: the above code can be run, please check the updated code, my question why Future.doWhile is blocking (even if i remove unawaited)

Comment: Can you please include the imported packages. `unawaited` is not part of the SDK.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, please check

Comment: Ok, `unawaited` from `pedantic` does nothing and is just a way to inform the linter to don't give a warning about future's you are now awaiting on. So the behavior of the program will not change with the use of `unawaited`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is not working as expected because the method you give `doWhile` is not returning any `Future` and can therefore be executed synchronously which it will.

You can change the code to the following:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:pedantic/pedantic.dart';

bool _asking = false;
String name = '';
Future main() async {
  unawaited(askUserName());
}

Future askUserName() async {
  _asking = true;
  //feedInfoToTheUser({'info': 'enter a name'});
  //print('enter the name');
  unawaited(Future.doWhile(() {
    if (name.isNotEmpty) {
      _asking = false;
      print('thank you');
      exit(0);
    }
    return Future.value(_asking);
  }));
  print('wow');
}
```

Here we return `Future.value(_asking)` which is a Future which will be evaluated as another event on the event queue which makes the `doWhile` method `await` for this evaluation. This make it so `wow` is written.

But you do still have an infinite loop (so the CPU usage is high). But it is now an infinite loop on the event queue which allow other stuff to be executed on the event queue in between each event.

Comment: I gave you a down vote because your question was not clear and your posted code did not even work. Also, you current code are not something you should ever use in production code since there are multiple ways to have the same behavior but without the wasted CPU resources. I have lifted my down vote now since your current code do work. But I still think you have a very wrong approach to you problem just by have this `doWhile` loop.

Comment: i understood, but the answer should focus on the problem rather than finding another problem in the code and answering to that